# Python Random in While Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a Python script that basically executes within a while loop:

```python
while 1:
  <do stuff>
```

What I'd like to do is have it perform an action at random like, once or twice ever hour or so.

I've tried solutions like if random.random() > 5: but it just happens way too often.

Any ideas how I can ensure it goes off once or twice an hour while not going off constantly?

Comment: Why not choose two random numbers between 0 and 59 and do it (once) when the minutes after the hour hit that. Then after both have been hit, redo.

Comment: @downshift it seems to me that periodicity is the *opposite* of random...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the randomizer to create a time for the action to run. This won't block your other actions in the loop.

```
import time
import random

def get_new_time_to_perform_action():
  delay_minutes = (30 + random.random() * 30) # 30-60 minutes
  return time.time() + delay_minutes * 60

next_time_to_run = get_new_time_to_perform_action()

while True:
  if (time.time() >= next_time_to_run):
    # <do action>
    next_time_to_run = get_new_time_to_perform_action()
  # <do other actions>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. You could use `np.random.normal(avg_wait,std_wait)` instead of `random.random()` to get more control and be able to separately change the average and stdev of the wait time.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be a good engineering decision put all tasks inside a loop coupled to a specific rule of an independent task.

Comment: Yup this is what I did.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a time window, it maybe a good option apply a sleep interval.

By example, you can do:

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint

while 1:
  <do stuff>
  sleep(randint(0, 3600))
```

Comment: I cant use sleep because I need the rest of the app to still run

Comment: In this case, If you have some shared resources inside <do stuff> with other parts of you program, this code snippet can run on another thread. If there is not shared resources, you can think about extract this block to an separated python script and schedule on crontab

Comment: You don't need a crontab to prevent blocking. Just pick a time to run with random. I've updated my code snippet as an example.

Comment: I just suggested cronjobs as a way to separate block of codes and think on independence of functionalities and asynchronous runtime. With one single crontab line it's possible to simplify a lot of concerns about sync and shared resources. Just an alternative

Answer (score 0):

To control the number of repetition each hour I would suggest picking an int with `random.randint` then to choose the exact moment the events will happend within the hour you could pick a float in [0,1[ with `random.random` and convert it to a number of seconds and wait with `time.sleep`.